# FFmpeg: what does the "global_header" flag do?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

According to the description, it *places global headers in extradata instead of every keyframe*.

But what's the actual purpose? Is it useful e.g. for streaming?

I guess that the resulting video file will be marginally shorter, but more prone to corruption (no redundancy = file unplayable if main header corrupted or only partially downloaded)?

Or maybe it somehow improves decoding a little bit? As headers are truly global and cannot change from keyframe to keyframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

By *extradata* `FFmpeg` means out-of-band, as opposed to in-band. The behavior of the flag is format specific. This is useful for headers that are not expected to change because it reduces the overhead.

Example: for `H.264` in `MP4` the `SPS` and `PPS` are stored in the `avcC` atom. For the same `H.264` stream in let's say `MPEG-TS` the sequences are repeated in the bitstream.